# Creating a list of custom Date Ranges for ease of use, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Given a date (such as today's date, "October 8th, 2020") and a list of date ranges (Yesterday, Tomorrow, Last Week, Next Week, Last Month, Next Month, etc.), how can we arrive at the necessary date ranges, via SQL.

```
Yesterday   2020-10-07 00:00:00.000 2020-10-07 23:59:59.000
Tomorrow    2020-10-09 00:00:00.000 2020-10-09 23:59:59.000
Last Week   2020-09-27 00:00:00.000 2020-10-03 23:59:59.000
Next Week   2020-10-11 00:00:00.000 2020-10-17 23:59:59.000
Last Month  2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 2020-09-30 23:59:59.000
Next Month  2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 2020-11-30 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: Date functions are highly vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Clarified title, added more specific tags.

Comment: Why do you think `23:59:59` is the end of a day? This has the potential to bite you in either direction (missing data or rounding up and including too much data). Try to think about a range as "greater than equal to the start of the range, and less than the beginning of _the next range_." Finding the beginning of next month is way easier than finding the end of this month.

Comment: Also see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/ and https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common and https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/ ... though this whole question and answer feels more like a blog post than a question and answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it exactly was a blog post.  They answered their own question

Comment: @SteveC Right but I'm not quite sure I understand why it's a question at all. This isn't some obscure technical problem that's been solved, it's a general "here's 400 lines of code that may or may not do a thing you're also trying to do" and doesn't really fit this format IMHO.

Comment: It was a question I asked last week (but didn't post to SO in search of my answer), and so when I answered it, I thought I would give back to SO in terms of the original question and the solution we arrived at.  Thank you, @AaronBertrand for the links, which I will read to improve our current solution.

Comment: This also might be helpful: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Q: RE: WITH NOLOCK, if the sysDates table is only ever written to once (or at least very infrequently), is there harm in WITH NOLOCK?  Yes, I added that everywhere, specifically because early in development I _thought_ I was encountering a lock condition, where it was in fact, a misplaced COMMIT TRANSACTION, but in this situation is there harm in leaving it be?

Comment: Regarding End Dates, I will pass a parameter into the routine that will control whether the "end date" is the "last value in the period" (which, as your blog post illustrated runs the risk of missing data) or "the first value of the next period.  I will do this because this is being interfaced into legacy code, and most places in that code will use the structure `WHERE [Date] >= A AND [Date] <= B` and we don't want that to catch elements from the next day that do not have a Time component.

Comment: Flip it around. If the table is only written to once, are you ever _gaining_ anything by using NOLOCK? And forget about this query. Note that people may learn from your code and they will take that lesson to other tables (most of which are _not_ write-once and so are even more susceptible to its problems).

Comment: You should plan to fix any queries that use `<= end of range` because `end of range` is only possible to determine reliably and precisely in very specific scenarios and only until anyone changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

We have, as a starting point, a Dates table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysDate](
    [DateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Day] [char](10) NULL,
    [DayOfWeek] [smallint] NULL,
    [DayOfMonth] [smallint] NULL,
    [DayOfYear] [smallint] NULL,
    [PreviousDay] [datetime] NULL,
    [NextDay] [datetime] NULL,
    [WeekOfYear] [smallint] NULL,
    [Month] [char](10) NULL,
    [MonthOfYear] [smallint] NULL,
    [QuarterOfYear] [smallint] NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [FiscalYearString] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [FiscalQuarter] [int] NULL,
    [FiscalQuarterStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FiscalQuarterEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FiscalYear] [int] NULL,
    [FiscalYearStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FiscalYearEndDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This we created years ago, and populated with data from 1900 to 2030, and it has as an added benefit the identification of Fiscal Periods.  Most business use a Fiscal Year that starts April 1, but this isn't always the case.

To address this challenge, we decided that we wanted the flexibility to add new ranges as the need arose, without requiring additional customization of the stored procedures that generated the ranges.  We then would need a table to hold the "recipie" for converting a date to its range.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomDateRanges](
    [DateRangeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateRangeLabel] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayOrder] [int] NULL,
    [isPast] [bit] NULL,
    [isPresent] [bit] NULL,
    [isFuture] [bit] NULL,
    [StartDateAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartDayOfWeekAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartDayOfMonthAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartDayOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartWeekOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartMonthOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartFiscalYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndDateAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndDayOfWeekAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndDayOfMonthAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndDayOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndWeekOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndMonthOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndFiscalYearAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster] [varchar](5) NULL
)
```

To identify a range, we now declare what manipulations are required to take a given date to the start of its range, and then the same date to the end of its range.  NULL columns in the `CustomDateRanges` table indicate that the field in question does not need any manipulation.  Permissible values in the Adjuster columns are:

```
+<number> -- used to add <number> to the element
-<number> -- used to subtract <number> from the element
<number>  -- used to explicitly set the element to <number>
'END'     -- used to set the element to its last valid value, but only for "End" adjusters
```

We added the data to `CustomDateRanges`

```
INSERT INTO CustomDateRanges(DateRangeLabel, DisplayOrder, isPast, isPresent, isFuture, StartDateAdjuster, StartDayOfWeekAdjuster, StartDayOfMonthAdjuster, StartDayOfYearAdjuster, StartWeekOfYearAdjuster, StartMonthOfYearAdjuster, StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster, StartYearAdjuster, StartFiscalYearAdjuster, StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster, EndDateAdjuster, EndDayOfWeekAdjuster, EndDayOfMonthAdjuster, EndDayOfYearAdjuster, EndWeekOfYearAdjuster, EndMonthOfYearAdjuster, EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster, EndYearAdjuster, EndFiscalYearAdjuster, EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster)
VALUES
-- DateRangeLabel                                StartDateAdjuster                  StartMonthOfYearAdjuster           EndDateAdjuster                    EndMonthOfYearAdjuster
-- |                                |DisplayOrder|      StartDayOfWeekAdjuster      |      StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster  |      EndDayOfWeekAdjuster        |      EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster
-- |                                |  isPast    |      |      StartDayOfMonthAdjuster     |      StartYearAdjuster    |      |      EndDayOfMonthAdjuster|      |      EndYearAdjuster
-- |                                |  |  isPresent     |      |      StartDayOfYearAdjuster      |      StartFiscalYearAdjuster     |      EndDayOfYearAdjuster |      |      EndFiscalYearAdjuster
-- |                                |  |  |  isFuture   |      |      |      StartWeekOfYearAdjuster     |      StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster  |      EndWeekOfYearAdjuster|      |      EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster
-- |                                |  |  |  |   |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
 ('Yesterday',                   NULL, 1, 0, 0,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Today',                       NULL, 0, 1, 0,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Tomorrow',                    NULL, 0, 0, 1,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Last Week',                   NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('This Week',                   NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Next Week',                   NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Last Month',                  NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('This Month',                  NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Next Month',                  NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,  NULL,   '1',  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Last Quarter',                NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('This Quarter',                NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Next Quarter',                NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL)
,('Last Fiscal Quarter',         NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END')
,('This Fiscal Quarter',         NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END')
,('Next Fiscal Quarter',         NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END')
,('Last Year',                   NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL)
,('This Year',                   NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL)
,('Next Year',                   NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL,  NULL)
,('Last Fiscal Year',            NULL, 1, 0, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '-1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL)
,('This Fiscal Year',            NULL, 0, 1, 0,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+0',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL)
,('Next Fiscal Year',            NULL, 0, 0, 1,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  '+1',  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL,  NULL, 'END',  NULL)
```

Then the code to perform the manipulations.  The first step in the code is to strip off the time component (via `CAST(CAST(@Date AS Date) AS DateTime)`, to ensure that lookups against the sysDate table are always accurate, and the last step in the code is to ensure that the StartDate always starts at Midnight, and EndDate always ends at `23:59:59`, ensuring complete date ranges.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CalculateCustomDateRange(@Date DateTime, @DateRangeID int, @EndDateIsBeginningOfNextRange bit)
AS
BEGIN

/**************************************************************************************************************************************************
* Copyright: CCD Health Systems
* Written by: Daniel Bragg                                                                                      
* Creation Date: 06-Oct-2020    
*
* Updates:
* Date          Author          Version     Purpose
* 2020-Oct-08   Daniel Bragg    5.0.0       Added @EndDateIsBeginningOfNextRange, to permit us to use the output for both 
*                                           ([D] >= Start AND [D] <= End) -- @EndDateIsBeginningOfNextRange = 0
*                                           and
*                                           ([D] >= Start AND [D] < End) -- @EndDateIsBeginningOfNextRange = 1
*
*************************************************************************************************************************************************/
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = CAST(CAST(@Date AS Date) AS DateTime)
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = @StartDate

-- Values from CustomDateRanges table
DECLARE @DateRangeLabel varchar(50),
    @DisplayOrder int,
    @isPast bit,
    @isPresent bit,
    @isFuture bit,
    @StartDateAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartDayOfWeekAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartDayOfMonthAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartDayOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartWeekOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartMonthOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartFiscalYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndDateAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndDayOfWeekAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndDayOfMonthAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndDayOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndWeekOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndMonthOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndFiscalYearAdjuster varchar(5),
    @EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster varchar(5)

SELECT @DateRangeLabel=DateRangeLabel, @DisplayOrder=DisplayOrder, @isPast=isPast, @isPresent=isPresent, @isFuture=isFuture
     , @StartDateAdjuster=StartDateAdjuster, @StartDayOfWeekAdjuster=StartDayOfWeekAdjuster, @StartDayOfMonthAdjuster=StartDayOfMonthAdjuster
     , @StartDayOfYearAdjuster=StartDayOfYearAdjuster, @StartWeekOfYearAdjuster=StartWeekOfYearAdjuster, @StartMonthOfYearAdjuster=StartMonthOfYearAdjuster
     , @StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster=StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster, @StartYearAdjuster=StartYearAdjuster, @StartFiscalYearAdjuster=StartFiscalYearAdjuster
     , @StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster=StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster, @EndDateAdjuster=EndDateAdjuster, @EndDayOfWeekAdjuster=EndDayOfWeekAdjuster
     , @EndDayOfMonthAdjuster=EndDayOfMonthAdjuster, @EndDayOfYearAdjuster=EndDayOfYearAdjuster, @EndWeekOfYearAdjuster=EndWeekOfYearAdjuster
     , @EndMonthOfYearAdjuster=EndMonthOfYearAdjuster, @EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster=EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster, @EndYearAdjuster=EndYearAdjuster
     , @EndFiscalYearAdjuster=EndFiscalYearAdjuster, @EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster=EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster
FROM CustomDateRanges  WHERE DateRangeID = @DateRangeID

DECLARE @DayOfWeek smallint,
    @DayOfMonth smallint,
    @DayOfYear smallint,
    @PreviousDay datetime,
    @NextDay datetime,
    @WeekOfYear smallint,
    @MonthOfYear smallint,
    @QuarterOfYear smallint,
    @Year int,
    @FiscalYear int,
    @FiscalQuarter int

DECLARE @AdjustFullYears int
DECLARE @AdjustRemainingQuarters int


DECLARE @Value int

--------------------------------
-- Perform Start Calculations --
--------------------------------

-- Set Date Specifics
SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate

IF (@StartFiscalYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartFiscalYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartFiscalYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartFiscalYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartFiscalYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SELECT @StartDate=MIN([Date]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear+@Value
    ELSE
        SELECT @StartDate=MIN([Date]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@Value

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartFiscalQuarterAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        BEGIN
        -- Simplify
        SET @FiscalQuarter=@FiscalQuarter+@Value
        WHILE (@FiscalQuarter > 4)
            BEGIN
            SET @FiscalYear=@FiscalYear+1
            SET @FiscalQuarter=@FiscalQuarter-4
            END
        WHILE (@FiscalQuarter < 1)
            BEGIN
            SET @FiscalYear=@FiscalYear-1
            SET @FiscalQuarter=@FiscalQuarter+4
            END

        SELECT @StartDate=MIN(FiscalQuarterStartDate) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear AND [FiscalQuarter]=@FiscalQuarter
        END
    ELSE
        SELECT @StartDate=MIN(FiscalQuarterStartDate) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear AND [FiscalQuarter]=@Value

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year+@Value, 1, 1)
    ELSE
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@Value, 1, 1)

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartQuarterOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1)
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(quarter, @QuarterOfYear+@Value-1, @StartDate)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1)
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(quarter, @Value, @StartDate)
        END

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartMonthOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartMonthOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartMonthOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartMonthOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartMonthOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), @Value, DAY(@StartDate))

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartWeekOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartWeekOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartWeekOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartWeekOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartWeekOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(week, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        SELECT TOP 1 @StartDate=[Date] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [WeekOfYear]=@Value ORDER BY [Year],[WeekOfYear],[Date]

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartDayOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartDayOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartDayOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartDayOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartDayOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1)
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, @Value, @StartDate)
        END

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartDayOfMonthAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartDayOfMonthAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartDayOfMonthAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartDayOfMonthAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartDayOfMonthAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), MONTH(@StartDate), @Value)

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartDayOfWeekAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartDayOfWeekAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartDayOfWeekAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartDayOfWeekAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartDayOfWeekAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(week, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        SELECT @StartDate=[Date] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [WeekOfYear]=@WeekOfYear AND [DayOfWeek]=@Value

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

IF (@StartDateAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@StartDateAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@StartDateAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@StartDateAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@StartDateAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, @Value, @StartDate)
    ELSE
        SET @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), MONTH(@StartDate), @Value)

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @StartDate
    END

------------------------------
-- Perform End Calculations --
------------------------------
-- NOTE!  End Date always starts from the Start Date as its calculation
SET @EndDate=@StartDate

-- Set Date Specifics
SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate

IF (@EndFiscalYearAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndFiscalYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndFiscalYearAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndFiscalYearAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear 
  ELSE IF (@EndFiscalYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndFiscalYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndFiscalYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndFiscalYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndFiscalYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SELECT @EndDate=[Date] FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear+@Value AND [DayOfYear]=1
    ELSE
        SELECT @EndDate=[Date] FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@Value AND [DayOfYear]=1
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

IF (@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=@FiscalYear AND [FiscalQuarter]=@FiscalQuarter
  ELSE IF (@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndFiscalQuarterAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        BEGIN
        SET @AdjustFullYears = @Value / 4
        SET @AdjustRemainingQuarters = @Value % 4

        -- Adjust to the beginning of the quarter, to not mess anything up.
        SELECT @EndDate=FiscalQuarterEndDate FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date]=@EndDate
        SET @EndDate=DATEADD(year, @AdjustFullYears, @EndDate)

        -- See if we need to adjust the year
        IF (@QuarterOfYear + @AdjustRemainingQuarters) > 4
            SELECT @EndDate=FiscalQuarterEndDate FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=YEAR(@EndDate)+1 AND [FiscalQuarter]=(@FiscalQuarter + @AdjustRemainingQuarters - 4) AND [DayOfMonth]=@DayOfMonth
        ELSE IF (@QuarterOfYear + @AdjustRemainingQuarters) < 1
            SELECT @EndDate=FiscalQuarterEndDate FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=YEAR(@EndDate)-1 AND [FiscalQuarter]=(@FiscalQuarter + @AdjustRemainingQuarters + 4) AND [DayOfMonth]=@DayOfMonth
        ELSE
            SELECT @EndDate=FiscalQuarterEndDate FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=YEAR(@EndDate) AND [FiscalQuarter]=(@FiscalQuarter + @AdjustRemainingQuarters) AND [DayOfMonth]=@DayOfMonth
        END
    ELSE
        SELECT @EndDate=FiscalQuarterEndDate FROM sysDate  WHERE [FiscalYear]=YEAR(@EndDate) AND [FiscalQuarter]=@Value AND [DayOfMonth]=@DayOfMonth
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

IF (@EndYearAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndYearAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndYearAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year
  ELSE IF (@EndYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(year, @Value, @EndDate)
    ELSE
        SET @EndDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@Value, MONTH(@EndDate), DAY(@EndDate))
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

IF (@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [QuarterOfYear]=@QuarterOfYear
  ELSE IF (@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndQuarterOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(quarter, @Value, @EndDate)
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @EndDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@EndDate), 1, 1)
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(quarter, @Value, @EndDate)
        END
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

IF (@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [MonthOfYear]=@MonthOfYear
  ELSE IF (@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndMonthOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(month, @Value, @EndDate)
    ELSE
        SET @EndDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@EndDate), @Value, DAY(@EndDate))
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

IF (@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster = 'END') OR ((@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster) = 1)
  BEGIN
  IF (@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster = 'END')
    SELECT @EndDate=MAX([DATE]) FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [WeekOfYear]=@WeekOfYear
  ELSE IF (@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @Value = CAST(@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster AS INT)
    IF LEFT(@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster,1) = '-' OR LEFT(@EndWeekOfYearAdjuster,1) = '+' -- Adjust
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(week, @Value, @EndDate)
    ELSE
        SELECT TOP 1 @EndDate=[Date] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Year]=@Year AND [WeekOfYear]=@Value ORDER BY [Year],[WeekOfYear],[Date]
    END
  -- Update Date Specifics
  SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate  WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
  END

-- Removed code for @EndDayOfYearAdjuster, @EndDayOfMonthAdjuster  and @EndDayOfWeekAdjuster for brevity, but it's the same as the above code for the matching @Start blocks, but with the extra 'END' processing

IF (@EndDateAdjuster IS NOT NULL) AND ISNUMERIC(@EndDateAdjuster) = 1
    BEGIN
    -- Nothing is required, the End Date is already the Start Date

    -- Update Date Specifics
    SELECT @DayOfWeek=[DayOfWeek], @DayOfMonth=[DayOfMonth], @DayOfYear=[DayOfYear], @WeekOfYear=WeekOfYear, @MonthOfYear=[MonthOfYear], @QuarterOfYear=[QuarterOfYear], @Year=[Year], @FiscalYear=[FiscalYear], @FiscalQuarter=[FiscalQuarter] FROM sysDate WHERE [Date] = @EndDate
    END


-- Return StartDate as the earliest point on that date
-- and EndDate as the lastest point on that date.
SELECT @Date AS [Date],
        @DateRangeID AS [DateRangeID],
        @DateRangeLabel AS [DateRangeLabel],
        CAST(CAST(@StartDate AS Date) AS DateTime) AS [StartDate],
        DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(CAST(@EndDate AS Date) AS DateTime))) AS [EndDate]
END
```